# How to install p4a and it's dependencies on windows

Tags: python, p4a

I am trying to install p4a but I don't know how to install its dependencies. It would be a great help if someone could tell me how to install it on windows.

Comment: did you check https://python-for-android.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/#installation, what issue did you face?

Comment: yes, I checked but i could not find the command to instal p4a dependencies in windows